# Can I delete HPWMISVC.log

Tags: process, logging

My SSD is running out of space of my HP laptop.

I came across HPWMISVC.log which is now over 1.1GB.

I assume it is just the log for the process HPWMISVC.exe known as HP Quick Launch WMI Service .  I don't know why it is so big.

Is it safe to delete?

Comment: As an intermediate solution, you could open the log file in notepad, delete the contents and save it. It should clear up some space and not impact the process.

Comment: Notepad may crash at that file size. The .exe should be end tasked before; if it marks the file as in-use, altering it will not work.

Comment: @mtak notepad crashes when I try to open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That file belongs to HP Quick Launch/System Event Utility/HPAsset component for HP Active Support.

You can safely delete it, but the file may be in use. If it is, stop the HP process (HPWMISVC.exe), delete the file and start the process again.

You can just end task the HPWMISVC.exe and then delete the file. The process will be reloaded at the next restart. To manually reload it, you can start it from 'Program Files' but that is not needed.

Generally, I would not recommend using that service at all because it has been known to cause lag in various applications and/or take unusual amounts of memory.

Comment: I deleted and it immediately reappeared with --2017:05:08:09:57:12:0795:CServiceModule::HandlerEx - start
2017:05:08:09:57:12:0798:SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE
2017:05:08:09:57:12:0801:dwOutVal  -- which keeps repeating.  Must be something wrong with me PC!

Comment: What size is the re-appeared one ? If it's still big, just uninstall that service.

Comment: it keeps getting bigger (21M now).  I stop the process when the system starts.  It would be interesting to know if it is a system error or something that can be fixed rather than deleting in case it is useful.

Comment: 21MB is fine. Just monitor from time to time so it won't grow to GB-rage.